# SERVER shows BLANK WHITE PAGE after submitting CORRECT login details

Tags: php, mysqli

I have written a login script using mysqli and the complete script works up till the part where I've actually entered correct details. If I leave the fields blank or input incorrect details it displays a message to the user .. which is great! But say I enter the correct username and password combination.. it doesn't direct to the page I've asked it to.. it just shows me a white screen... see code below:

```
<?php
    // Create a connection
    include("dbconfig.php");    

    if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

        if( empty( $_POST['username'] ) or empty( $_POST['password'] ) ){

            header("location:index.php?msg0=Please complete the required fields.");

        } elseif ( !empty( $_POST['username'] ) && !empty( $_POST['password'] ) ){

            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username, password FROM logininformation WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'") or die (mysqli_error($conn));
            $login = ($sql) ? mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql) : false;

            if( $login == 0 ){
                header("location: index.php?msg1=Invalid username or password, please try again.");
            } elseif( $login == 1 ){
                header("location: userlogin.php?uid=$username");
            }
       }    
    }
?>
```

Please could someone advise me on what I'm doing wrong. Help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Sohail.

Comment: White page usually means "Internal Error: 500" or, you've simply not turned on error reporting - Turning on error reporting will tell you what to do none the less, either in the browser or checking your error log.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.. how do you switch error reporting on?

Comment: Place `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top of your page, right after the first `<?php`

Comment: It still doesn't display anything, even with the error reporting function switched on.

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows()` would have been a better function to use here, or `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's crazy, answering my own question... but I found the solution. See below:

Before:

```
elseif(($login) == 1){

header("location:userlogin.php?uid=$username");
```

After:

```
elseif(($login) > 1){

header("location:userlogin.php?uid=$username");
```

Comment: perhaps using `$login->num_rows==1` would be better?

Comment: how would you integrate that into my elseif statement?

Comment: probably like: `if( $login && $login->num_rows==1 ){/*success*/} else { /*fail*/ }`

Comment: hmm... personally, I feel that may confuse things, my solution has solved the problem I was having. However, I will try what you just said and maybe use it as a secondary option, if the first one ever goes bust.

Answer (score 1):

In the last elseif condition of your code, try removing the checking of ==1 and then run the code ... if still not working then try and paste the error log file here.